# Finding number groups from a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following list of string:

```
M64.933,9.425
M53.333,19
M81.333,20.67
M90,33
```

and I need to extract the groups of number integer or decimal, I have the following regexp **(\d*.*\d+)** that works for the first group my result is:

```
["64.933", "64.933"]
["53.333", "53.333"]
["81.333", "81.333"]
["90", "90"]
```

respectively, how can I get the second group? like this:

```
["64.933", "9.425"]
["53.333", "19"]
["81.333", "20.67"]
["90", "33"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this regular expression `/\d+(\.\d+)?/g`:

```javascript
var s = 'M64.933,9.425';
s.match(/\d+(\.\d+)?/g); // => ["64.933", "9.425"]
```

For example:

```javascript
var ss = ["M64.933,9.425", "M53.333,19", "M81.333,20.67", "M90,33"]
var ns = ss.map(function(s) { return s.match(/\d+(\.\d+)?/g); });
ns // => [["64.933","9.425"],["53.333","19"],["81.333","20.67"],["90","33"]]
```